# Sql query with non-trivial join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables that I am trying to join in a query, but I'm having some difficulty getting the required output.

Table: Scans

```
ScanId  ScanTime
1        8:00
2        8:15
3        9:00
4        9:30
6       10:00
7       10:45
8       11:00
9       11:10
```

Table: Responses

```
ScanId  RespA  RespB
3       ABC    X
7       DEF    Y
9       GHI    Z
```

There is a foreign key on Responses.ScanId that references Scans.ScanId.

The Responses table may or may not have a corresponding row for each row in the Scans table.

What I need to do is produce the output shown below, each row in the Scans table is returned with the most recent previous response values.

For Scans.ScanId 1 and 2, there is no previous response so the Response columns are null.

For Scans.ScanId 3, 4 and 6, the most recent previous RespA is ABC and RespB is X (ScanId=3)

For Scans.ScanId 7 and 8, the most recent previous RespA is DEF and RespB is Y (ScanId=7)

For Scan.ScanId 9, the most recent previous RespA is GHI and RespB is Z (ScanId=9)

Desired Output:

```
ScanId  ScanTime  RespScanId  RespA  RespB
1        8:00     NULL        NULL   NULL
2        8:15     NULL        NULL   NULL
3        9:00     3           ABC    X
4        9:30     3           ABC    X
6       10:00     3           ABC    X
7       10:45     7           DEF    Y
8       11:00     7           DEF    Y
9       11:10     9           GHI    Z
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to write the join clause for this one.  It needs to run on Sql Server 2005 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a solution using a CTE...](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118263/)

```
DECLARE @Scans TABLE (
    ScanID INT,
    ScanTime DATETIME
)

DECLARE @Responses TABLE (
    ScanID INT, 
    RespA VARCHAR(50),
    RespB VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (1, '8:00')
INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (2, '8:15')
INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (3, '9:00')
INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (4, '9:30')
INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (6, '10:00')
INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (7, '10:45')
INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (8, '11:00')
INSERT INTO @Scans VALUES (9, '11:10')

INSERT INTO @Responses VALUES (3, 'ABC', 'X')
INSERT INTO @Responses VALUES (7, 'DEF', 'Y')
INSERT INTO @Responses VALUES (9, 'GHI', 'Z')

;WITH ResponsesScan AS
(
    SELECT
        r.*, s.ScanTime
    FROM
        @Responses r
        JOIN @Scans s ON s.ScanID = r.ScanID
)
SELECT
    s.ScanID,
    s.ScanTime,
    rs.ScanID AS RespScanId,
    rs.RespA,
    rs.RespB
FROM
    @Scans s 
    LEFT JOIN ResponsesScan rs
        ON rs.ScanID = (
            SELECT TOP 1 ScanID
            FROM ResponsesScan
            WHERE ScanTime <= s.ScanTime
            ORDER BY ScanTime DESC
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

With the use of a windowing function:

```
SELECT S.ScanId, ScanTime, R.ScanId AS RespScanId, RespA, RespB
FROM Scans S
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ScanId, 
                        RespA, 
                        RespB, 
                        LEAD(ScanId) OVER(ORDER BY ScanId) AS NextScanId
                 FROM Responses) R
    ON S.ScanId >= R.ScanId 
   AND (S.ScanId < R.NextScanId OR R.NextScanID IS NULL);
```

Which returns on PostgreSQL according to your resultset :

```
 scanid | scantime | respscanid | respa | respb 
--------+----------+------------+-------+-------
      1 | 08:00:00 |            |       | 
      2 | 08:15:00 |            |       | 
      3 | 09:00:00 |          3 | ABC   | X
      4 | 09:30:00 |          3 | ABC   | X
      6 | 10:00:00 |          3 | ABC   | X
      7 | 10:45:00 |          7 | DEF   | y
      8 | 11:00:00 |          7 | DEF   | y
      9 | 11:10:00 |          9 | GHI   | Z
```

Comment: I'm getting "'LEAD' is not a recognized built-in function name.
".  Running on Sql Server 2005 and Sql Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @JSR: Ugh, I thought SQL Server implemented LAG and LEAD functions in the 2005 version, seems not. This makes my answer useless, I'll mark it as community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

My inner query gets the scan ID and the minimum scan ID above it.. if none other, then it has NULL as the "NextScan" value.  Then, I join that to the scans.  I qualify each one so that the scan ID is at least the one in question, but LESS than the scan following it.

```
SELECT 
      scans.scanID,
      scans.scanTime,
      rsp3.ScanID,
      rsp3.RespA,
      rsp3.RespB
   from 
      scans
         LEFT JOIN 
            ( SELECT rsp.scanID,
                  ( select MIN( rsp2.scanID ) 
                            from responses rsp2
                            where rsp2.scanID > rsp.ScanID ) as NextScan
                 from 
                    responses rsp ) PQ 
            on Scans.ScanID >= PQ.ScanID
            AND Scans.ScanID <= case when PQ.NextScan IS NULL
                                     then PQ.ScanID
                                     else PQ.NextScan -1
                                end
            LEFT JOIN Responses rsp3
               on PQ.ScanID = rsp3.ScanID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.scanid, s.scantime, xjoin.RespScanId, r.respa, r.respb 
from scans s
left join 
-- begin trick
    (select si.scanid, max(ri.scanid) as RespScanId
    from scans si
    left join responses ri on si.scanid >= ri.scanid
    group by si.scanid)  as  xjoin
-- end trick
       on s.scanid = xjoin.scanid
left join responses r on xjoin.RespScanId = r.scanid
```

Comment: just edited to correct a minor error. works perfect. and it is a clean syntax for almost any rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Michael Fredrickson's Common Table Expression, here is another version of the select query.

Although this query is admittedly more complicated, it has different performance characteristics (i.e. it might perform better).  However, the performance difference is trivial if you index the ScanTime column.

```
select
    s.ScanId,
    s.ScanTime,
    rs.ScanId as RespScanId,
    rs.RespA,
    rs.RespB
from Scans s
left outer join ResponsesScan rs on
    -- either there is a response for this specific scan
    rs.ScanId = s.ScanId
    or (
        -- or there is a response from a previous scan
        rs.ScanTime < s.ScanTime
        -- and there does not exist any other response
        and not exists (
            select 1
            from ResponsesScan rs2
            where
                -- for this specific scan
                rs2.ScanId = s.ScanId
                or (
                    -- or from a previous scan
                    rs2.ScanTime < s.ScanTime
                    -- that is later than that response
                    and rs2.ScanTime > rs.ScanTime
                )
        )
    )
```